# many connections from servlet to SQL server, which work together, cause javaw.exe to rise excessively

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, servlets, javaw

I have an android application which connects to a servlet (running by tomcat),
and that servlet connects to a SQL server by a **data source**.

Now, When we are talking about a single connection, by using:

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:NameOfMyDataSource");
```

Everything works well.

The problem is, the application uses a connection for calling a stored procedure which goes on and on (like it should), and after few seconds the user should be able to call another stored procedure by another connection:

```
Connection con2 = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:abc");
```

I have many connections like these : (con28, con29, con30), and the problem is that too many times I have a case, when the new stored procedure is not called , and all what I see is javaw.exe in the task manager rise to 25.

In order to release it I need to restart the tomcat server, or kill the current running proc inside SQLServer every time it happens.

I've heard about something which is called pool, but I couldn't make it for SQL server, and I don't know if this is what I need at all.

If someone have any idea I'll appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not closing your db connections. post the code in your servlet

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your response. I do close all the connections. There is no place in this comment box to write the code from myservlet but in general, it is going like this:   switch(x)  case "A": try{               con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:NameOfMyDataSource");                                                                        ......}.finally{
               if (rs!=null)
          rs.close();
         if (pstmt!=null)
           pstmt.close();
         if (con1!=null)
          con1.close();

......}